# How to extract taxes paid from the image using Python?

Tags: python, ocr

As a cool side project I am trying to extract the total taxes paid from an image of the tax receipt:

[image: Tax Receipt]

I would want to parse this image (and similar others) and would like to extract the tax amount.

which is `[383.58,0.53,0.53, 383.58]`

Can somebody give me leads to get started? I tried starting with OCR and used some free online OCR programs and none of them seem to read the data correctly.

How to approach this problem? I have tried online OCR so far. Which are the engines best suited for this purpose and what are key things to keep in mind?

Are there good libraries in python which can help me get started?

I have tried online programs using Tesseract-OCR and they did not read the numbers correctly. My hunch is tinkering the parameters of this engine should help, but am lost trying to understand what parameters could help and where to start.

I am just starting with these things so trying to find my way through without necessarily understanding the underlying technical details.

Comment: OCR is the standard way to extract text from image. What libraries or resources you tried. Would you mind including that in your question.

Comment: "Can somebody give me leads to get started?" - way too broad, unfortunately. "Is OCR a good starting point?" - opinion-based. "Which are the engines best suited for this purpose and what are key things to keep in mind?" - also too broad. "Are there good libraries in python which can help me get started?" - asking for library recommendations is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

[Tesseract-OCR](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) is a respectable open-source OCR library. Though it's written in C++, there are many documentation involving wrappers using Python.

- [Tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/10/using-tesseract-ocr-python/)
- [PyTesseract](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract)
- [PyOCR](https://github.com/openpaperwork/pyocr)